# GAE mail API reply_to feature

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail

I have a feedback form, where users can leave comments. These comments will be emailed to me and users' email address will appears as reply_to in the header, which means I can address these comments if I click the "reply" button in the GMAIL. However, it seems like the 'reply-to' header does not work. Every time I click 'reply', I am writing to myself. Any suggestions?

The basic function is defined as below:

HTML CODE

```
<!-- The contact form-->    
<form method="POST" action=contactus_output.html>
    <table align="center" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">
        <tr><th colspan="2" align="left"><h1>Contact Form</h1></th></tr> 
        <tr><th>Name:</th><td><input type="text" name="nm.name" id="id.name" required="required" /></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Email:</th><td><input type="email" name="nm.email" id="id.email" required="required" /></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Subject:</th><td><select id="sub" name="nm.sub" required="required"/><option value="" selected="selected">Select one of the subjects</option><option value="1" >Suggestion</option><option value="Bug report" >Bug report</option><option value="Other" >Other</option></select></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Message:</th></tr>
        <tr><th></th><td><textarea id="msg" rows="10" cols="40" name="nm.msg" required="required"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value=" Let us know! "></td></tr>
    </table>
 </form>
```

Python CODE

```
#define the function
def sendanemail(name,subj, rply, msg):
    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Support <myapp@gmail.com>")
    message.subject = subj
    message.to = "Ubertool Support <myapp@gmail.com>" 
    message.reply_to= rply
    message.cc = rply   
    message.body = '''A message submitted by %s, %s \n''' %(name, rply)
    message.body = message.body+msg
    message.send()

def post(self):        
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    name = form.getvalue('nm.name')
    rply = form.getvalue('nm.email')
    subj = form.getvalue('nm.sub')
    msg = form.getvalue('nm.msg')
    sendanemail(name,subj, rply, msg)
```

Email header

```
from:    Support myapp@gmail.com via 2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com 
reply-to:    abc@gmail.com
to:  Support <myapp@gmail.com>
cc:  abc@gmail.com
date:    Thu, Sep 20, 2012 at 5:20 PM
subject:     Other
mailed-by:   2uix4h7xygsz66weerlq.apphosting.bounces.google.com
```

The problem is I click 'reply', my GMAIL replies to 'myapp@gmail.com', not 'abc@gmail.com'

Comment: It's working for me. Can you post your actual code (the `user@gmail.com` without quotes is suspicious). Can you also post an extract of the original raw email (show original in gmail).

Comment: Strange, the header is actually there. Are the headers lowercase?

Comment: Yes. Is it because "from" and "to" are the same email address?

Comment: I think you are right, I tried it and I'm seeing the same behavior. When you reply using the account that sent the message it replies to that account, but if you reply using the cc'ed account replying works fine.

Comment: In the meantime, you can send the email from you appspotmail address ( <app-id>@<app-id>.appspotmail.com

Comment: @SebastianKreft: using <app-id>@<app-id>.appspotmail.com as the sender solved the problem. Thanks for your help! How can I set this as a solution?

Comment: I added a summary of the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a summary of the comments.

The problem seems to be related to Gmail, as the Reply-To header is actually sent, and is because the sender and receiver are the same.

A workaround is to have a different sender and receiver address, to achieve that the email address `<app-id>@<app-id>.appspotmail.com` can be used.